# Is there a triangle array that takes the preceding number and adds one for the first and subtracts one for the second term?

Tags: triangles

I was wondering if there is a triangle array that would produce

```
0
1,-1
2,0,0,-2
3,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-3
4,2,2,0,2,0,0,-2,2,0,0,-2,0,-2,-2,-4
```

where i becomes i+1, i-1

I'm looking for a way to determine if @ row x and position y the value is 0.

Comment: Hint: your $n$th row has $2^n$ entries in it. (The 0 is, of course, row 0!) Pick some row $n$, write out the binary expansion of the numbers from $0$ to $2^{n-1}$, and see if you can find any correlation between the number of 'on' bits in the expansion of position $y$ and the value of your array in that position...

Comment: That's where I generated it from. To make a long story short for a comment. All zero's in this triangle is where there are equal number of 1's and zeros when a number is written as a bit. Row 2 is for max one bit 0 (-1) and 1 (1). Row three is 00 (-2),01 (0),10 (0),11 (2) Row 3 000 (-3), 001 (-1), 010 (-1), 011 (1), 100 (-1), 101 (1), 110 (1), 111 (3). I was just curious if there was already a triangle describing this.